# Favorite questions and answers from the first quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from January 1st 2015 through March 31st 2015.

How do I convince meta this question is unique to the 10-odd similarly asked questions each quarter? Via the power of lies, damn lies, and statistics.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

**What was the best answer (IYHO) provided to a question that was closed?**

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)

Comment: [Eligible Questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/292100/questions-created-in-q1-2015)

Comment: [Eligible Answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/292102/answers-created-in-q1-2015)

Answer (score 5):

My favorite questions (all Star Wars, sorry!)

- [Why did Red Squadron give their call signs in random order?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83209/why-did-red-squadron-give-their-call-signs-in-random-order)
- [Why did Jango Fett have a son via cloning instead of through natural reproductive processes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83490/why-did-jango-fett-have-a-son-via-cloning-instead-of-through-natural-reproductiv)

My favorite answers:

- The only answer to [How big is the Executor, based only on film evidence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83005/how-big-is-the-executor-based-only-on-film-evidence)
- [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83917/4678) to [During the war of the ring did Sauron or Saruman actually win any major battles?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83912/during-the-war-of-the-ring-did-sauron-or-saruman-actually-win-any-major-battles)

Comment: Heh, I liked the Fett question, too, for obvious reasons. It started off badly downvoted, though; for a minute I thought I had a shot at the Reversal badge.

Answer (score 4):

I thought these were especially interesting questions;

[Why didn't the machine kill Neo after he was ejected?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80366/why-didnt-the-machine-kill-neo-after-he-was-ejected)

[Why do people risk death by joining Starfleet if not for money or preservation of their homes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82442/why-do-people-risk-death-by-joining-starfleet-if-not-for-money-or-preservation-o)

[Did Darth Vader ever talk to R2-D2 again?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79862/did-darth-vader-ever-talk-to-r2-d2-again)

And my answers to them weren't half bad, either, if I can toot my own trumpet.

Comment: Campaigning for rep again, I see...

Comment: "if I can toot my own trumpet" - you seem to do that a lot here! ;-) Also, https://xkcd.com/757/

Comment: @SSumner - It's mere coincidence, I can assure you...

Answer (score 2):

I enjoyed this one: [Why is 'Belgium' the rudest word in Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83573/why-is-belgium-the-rudest-word-in-hitchikers-guide-to-the-galaxy)
Lots of votes and lots of reputation gained for everyone involved.

Richard got an awesome answer to this one precisely one minute before I did, and did a much better job of it than I did too, so it's worth a shout-out: [Why didn't the machine kill Neo after he was ejected?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80366/why-didnt-the-machine-kill-neo-after-he-was-ejected)

Obligatory blowing of one's own trumpet: [Why would the elves help destroy the One Ring?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81477/why-would-the-elves-help-destroy-the-one-ring)

And this was enormous fun all-round: [How big is the Death Star compared to the Executor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82987/how-big-is-the-death-star-compared-to-the-executor)